# Where is Windows log files directory?

Tags: c#

Hey guys so I have been working on a program for a while, I'm sorta a noob at coding been doing it for about a year (inconsistently) anyways basically this program cleans directories like  cookies, internet history etc. But I can't find the log files?

Comment: Logfiles of what? this doesnt sound like a stack overflow question

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean MS Windows? It's event viewer, you can find it in administrative tools

Comment: Yeah I guess but I need it in directory cause for C# I won't know how to clean it other wise.

Comment: I guess it helps you https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277418.aspx </br> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722318.aspx

Comment: Thanks I looked but didn't give me the information I hoped for.